# Security alert - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, security, lodash

I've gotten notice from github that one of my packages has a security alert, please see: https://github.com/ekkis/js-prototype-lib/network/alerts

the thing though is my package has no dependencies.  it has a developer dependency on *mocha* for the test suite but not on the offending package lodash

so how do I address this?

Comment: could anyone illuminate me as to why I've received a downgrade?

Comment: I did not downvote, but maybe it's because the info to describe your problem is on an external site, instead of in a quoted text in the post itself. As of now, the link now leads to a 404 page, so basically, we don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: ah.  it leads to a 404 because the problem's been fixed.  I see I got 2 downvotes.  I really hate that mechanism where people can downvote without feedback to make the posting better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer seems to be `npm audit fix`